# timthumb not finding image

Tags: php, wordpress, timthumb

I'm building a site using wordpress installed on localhost.

For some reason my post.php page is not displaying post thumbnails (featured images). I have identified that it is a problem with timthumb.php which is not correctly locating the image url. I have searched for hours online and tried a number of solutions but nothing seems to be working.

The basic problem is I think in this line in my blog.php file:

```
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img class="postimg" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php get_image_url(); ?>&amp;h=200&amp;w=470&amp;zc=1" alt=""/></a>
<?php }

else { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img class="postimg" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/dummy.png" alt="" /></a>
<?php } ?>
```

My functions.php script defines get_image_url as follws:

```
function get_image_url(){
    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'large');
    $image_url = $image_url[0];
    echo $image_url;
    }
```

In the site it returns the dummy.png image (broken image) - when I right click the image and open in a new tab the error I get is:

"A Timthumb Error has occurred - Cannot find the internal image that you specified"

It then shows my query string:

```
Query String : src=http://localhost/wordpress/frouzeh/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2013/04/PurpleNecklace.png&h=200&w=470&zc=1
```

however if I actually go to the image using the URL:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/frouzeh/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2013/04/PurpleNecklace.png
```

the image show up fine

- I am developing on windows using the local host so it can't be a permission control for the folders
- Using the latest version of timthumb 2.8.11
- I have tried removing the resizing parameters: &h=200&w=470&zc=1 from the file but still get the same error
- I have enabled (as some solutions suggest in the timthumb.php file):

  define ('ALLOW_ALL_EXTERNAL_SITES', TRUE);
- There is no tilde in my site name as other solutions suggest.

I'm really at a loss here. And would appreciate any help - seems like it may be a simple syntax error or something but I can't find it.

Comment: your code is right but check your theme in cache folder in timthumb file generated or not.

Comment: Hi ravi - tried deleting the cache folder entirely then recreating it. It was empty, and I updated my test site and 2 files were added to the cache folder - "index.html" and "timthumb_cacheLastCleanTime.touch" so that seems to be working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying to fix this for hours, I decided to move my wordpress site to a live server (linux). I then changed the access permissions to the Cache folder to 755 and my images came back.

This was a permission problem, however I am still unsure why it wouldn't work on my windows machine even after going through properties of the cache folder and changing the permissions there - any insight would be appreciated...

Comment: I am having the exact opposite problem but if you check inside the thumb.php, there should be line 212: 

    $this->src = preg_replace('/https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?' . $this->myHost . '/i', '', $this->src);

make sure it is NOT comment out.

i have something like 
src=wordpress/frouzeh/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2013/04/PurpleNecklace.png&h=200&w=470&zc=1 
which is terrible for me (because I might be missing some setting)
but it should work for you.

Comment: one possible problem can be the *guid* in the *wp_post* table, it should have the current server address.